# Navigate to previous directory in windows command prompt

Tags: windows, command-line

Is there any command / tool to navigate previous directory in windows command prompt?

In linux usually use

```
cd -
```

for previous directory navigation.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Save the following to eg. `mycd.bat` somewhere in your path:

```
@echo off
if '%*'=='' cd & exit /b
if '%*'=='-' (
    cd /d %OLDPWD%
    set OLDPWD=%cd%
) else (
    cd /d %*
    if not errorlevel 1 set OLDPWD=%cd%
)
```

Then always remember to use `mycd` instead of `cd` to change directories and drives.

Alternatively, use a `doskey` macro:

```
C:\>doskey cd=mycd $*
```

The only caveat is if you omit the space between `cd` and `..` or `\`, you will get the builtin version of `cd` not the `doskey` macro... and you still have to remember not to use `C:`, `D:` etc. to change drive.

Comment: It looks like it shouldn't work, but it does. OLDPWD gets set correctly.

Comment: +1 This is nice , it works! but painful to use mycd (or whtevr )

Comment: @HughAllen can make a doskey macro for cd\ and cd.. doskey cd\=cd \  or doskey cd\=c:\mycd.bat \    doskey C:=c:\mycd.bat C:

Comment: That bat will fail for c:\blah.bat %USERPROFILE%  (so cd or cdd %USERPROFILE% will fail). To fix, change single quotes to double quotes.

Answer (score 50):

You can use pushd and popd:

```
C:\WINDOWS>pushd \
C:\>popd
C:\WINDOWS>
```

Comment: Thx John, But this is not exactly what i am looking for.

Comment: It's exactly what I want for my batch scripts, thanks.  It even  changes drives without needing the \d switch

Comment: __Warning__ With `pushd/popd` you __have to considerate the possibility of errors__. In a script when you `pushd` a directory that doesn't exists it will not finish in the stack, but when you `popd` you will exit of one level: variable not filled correctly,missprint,wrong drive... You think to be in a directory different from the one in which you are, with serious problem e.g. when you delete files/dirs. Disaster (Linux syntax): `cd $HOME;  mkdir A; pushd A;  mkdir B; pushd D; do stuff (in A, you believe in B); popd; rm -rf * ` you believe in A but...too late, all your home directory is gone.

Comment: Thanks. It's the best and easiest way.

Answer (score 5):

if you are running the batch file you can use

```
  cd /D  %~dp0
```

This will jump back to the original path from where the batch file was run

Answer (score 5):

If you want the exact behavior of bash, why not use bash? I have [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) installed and it is very nice. It doesn't make you stick to its UNIX tools - it will happily call any windows executable. For `cmd.exe` builtins you can create an alias:

```
hugh@comp07 ~/testdir                             
$ alias cm='cmd /c'                               

hugh@comp07 ~/testdir                             
$ cm dir                                          
 Volume in drive C has no label.                  
 Volume Serial Number is AC2A-8378                

 Directory of C:\cygwin\home\hugh\testdir         

18/05/2010  02:02 PM    <DIR>          .          
18/05/2010  02:02 PM    <DIR>          ..         
               0 File(s)              0 bytes     
               2 Dir(s)   1,365,155,840 bytes free

hugh@comp07 ~/testdir                             
$
```

Answer (score 3):

There's a freeware `cmd` clone with extra features including `cd -` called [Take Command Console LE](http://www.jpsoft.com/tccledes.htm).

[image]

Comment: This doesn't work

Comment: @TiNS: OK I just tried it and it worked for me. What did it do for you?

Comment: I tried with console (from main window)

Comment: @TiNS: I'm not clear on what you did, but maybe this screenshot will help? (answer updated)

Answer (score 1):

Depending what your goal is, you could just start a new cmd session by doing 'cmd', move directory and do whatever you want, when you then do 'exit' to leave the session you'll be back in the directory you were when you started the new session.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is very great for the requirement. While I often have to switch among many recent directories instead of just just two (current and previous).

So I recently made a batch to make my daily jobs easier. 
https://gist.github.com/programus/2d2738b2a746140186f7738b678bdcec

Comment: It's so easy to type `cdx :`. Thanks! It should be the top upvoted answer.

Answer (score 0):

What I do is

```
rem capture the path of the initial dir
set RET_DIR=%CD%
rem do stuff...
rem and then return to the initial dir
cd %RET_DIR%
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been using this little-known program for directory changing on Linux and Windows for over 12 years and I really don't understand why many more people don't use it because it's brilliant.

CD Deluxe lets you change to the last directory with `cd -` and you can go to the second last directory with `cd -2` and the third with `cd -3` and do on. Just `cd` will give you the directory history.

https://github.com/m6z/cd-deluxe

Answer (score 0):

You can easily make a `doskey` macro to navigate to previous directory.

```
rem test.bat

@echo off
doskey cdx=@echo off$tpushd %cd%$T$tcd $1$t@echo on
doskey rcdx=popd
cmd
echo on
```

Save the above code to any batch file and whenever you want to open command prompt, open this file.

I have used `pushd` command to save current directory in stack and whenever you want to get back to previous directory, you can use `rcdx` or `popd` command.

Disadvantage: high memory usage by cmd if `cdx` command is used many times.