# "cd -" equivalent on Windows?

Tags: windows, linux, unix, cd

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Navigate to previous directory in windows command prompt](https://superuser.com/questions/129969/navigate-to-previous-directory-in-windows-command-prompt)

Is there an equivalent of Linux's `cd -` (change to previous directory) in Windows?

Answer (score 5):

`popd`, which is to be used alongside `pushd`.

Answer (score 1):

See [Navigate to previous directory in windows command prompt](https://superuser.com/questions/129969/navigate-to-previous-directory-in-windows-command-prompt)

Answer (score -1):

Yeah, it's identical, [see here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cd_%28command%29):

> `cd` is frequently included built directly into the command line interpreter. This is the case in most of the Unix shells (Bourne shell, tcsh, bash, etc.), cmd.exe and Windows PowerShell on Windows and COMMAND.COM on DOS.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: -1 because cd is subtly different on Windows/DOS compared to Linux, and the OP question was about a specific option which doesn't work on the windows version.