# How to use cd effectively in the Windows console?

Tags: windows, command-line

I'm a Linux user just starting to get the hang of Windows 7. How can one perform these functions with the Windows cd command:

1. Go back to the previous directory (cd - in Bash)
2. Go to the user's home directory (cd ~ in Bash)
3. Bookmark a directory (not built into bash, but cdargs or DerB can be added)

Comment: As pointed out in comments to answers, this duplicates two existing questions: [this](http://superuser.com/questions/129969/) and [this](http://superuser.com/questions/129969/).

Comment: Windows also supports the `pushd` and `popd` commands, though with much less flexibility than, say, their bash versions.

Comment: @JdeBP what you called "this and this" , the two links are the same, should just read "this".

Comment: No, barlop.  **Please** apply some nous for once.  A correct statement is that the second hyperlink, clearly a copy and paste error on my part, should be [this](http://superuser.com/questions/332871/), as given below in the comments _if you'd only thought_ to look.

Comment: @JdeBP You know you've written this this this and this so many times, in so many places, for this question, that it's difficult to see whether and when you're linking to a "this" that you've already linked to. I will clarify by putting them in one comment.  and with no hovering required. http://superuser.com/questions/129969/navigate-to-previous-directory-in-windows-command-prompt   http://superuser.com/questions/332871/    (journeyman also mentioned the 129969 one).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
1.  
C:\blah>pushd a
C:\blah\a>popd
C:\blah>


2. 
cd %userprofile%

3. 
C:\>doskey gocq=cd c:\cq
C:\>gocq <ENTER>
C:\cq>
```

Answer (score 0):

`cd ..` to go one level up

`cd \` to go to the root level of the drive

`cd %UserProfile%` to go to the equivilent of /home - its c:/users/username in windows 7

Comment: I think by *the previous directory* they didn't mean to go *up*, but one step back in the "history", so to say.

Comment: ahh, that would be covered by this http://superuser.com/questions/129969/navigate-to-previous-directory-in-windows-command-prompt

Comment: And the other `cd` command is covered by [this SuperUser question](http://superuser.com/questions/332871).

Comment: "cd /" really?  come on man.. \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\  You're not helping him by using forward slashes when writing what are blatantly windows directories.

Comment: my bad. fixed. surprised no one caught it ;p